# A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Code goes as follows, I am trying to use training data for GBRT regression trees, same data works good for other classifiers but gives above error for GBRT. please help :

```
dataset = load_files('train')
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(encoding='latin1')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform((open(f).read() for f in dataset.filenames)) 
assert sp.issparse(X_train)     
print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X_train.shape)
y_train = dataset.target
def benchmark(clf_class, params, name):
    clf = clf_class(**params).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: if you are using `GradientBoostingRegressor` it doesn't accept sparse matrices as input.

Comment: I Converted using 
arX = np.array(X_train).
 but now the error says 'tuple index out of range '

Comment: do as it says in the error. `Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array`. so `X_train.toarray()`

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' (type of X_train) object has no attribute 'toarray'

Answer (score 16):

I came accross the same problem trying to train a `GradientBoostingClassifier` using the data loaded by `load_svmlight_files`. Solved by transforming a sparse matrix to a numpy array.

```
X_train.todense()
```

Answer (score 5):

Because **GBRT** in **sklearn** request X (**training data**) is `array-like` not `sparse matrix`: [sklearn-gbrt](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.fit)

I hope this could help you!

Comment: I Converted using arX = np.array(X_train). but now the error says 'tuple index out of range ' –

Comment: X_train is `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` is not a `list` in native python

Comment: I am converting 
from <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> 
to <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
still gives tuple error.

Comment: well np.array(X_train) doesn't convert. It wraps the sparse matrix into a 1x1 array of dtype object. Have you looked at the error message?

Comment: It doesn't give an error! whats the best way I can use sparce.csr_matrix in GBRT classifier..? How to convert it to Dense array data?

Answer (score 1):

`OneHotEncoder` is no longer supported with Latest version of `sklearn` library. The code is modified to user `ColumnTransformer`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer([('town', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder = 'passthrough')

X = ct.fit_transform(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use OneHotEncoder of sklearn.

You need to use the following:

**from sksurv.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).